# SQL Query to get sum of amount, of children users based on Parent

Tags: mysql

i am trying to write an MySQL query where,

**AIM : to get data month wise like this**

```
MAY    20000    //sum of total amount earned by team (me and children alloted to my team)
June   23432
July   34488
```

I have a table with name `foadc_invoice`. In which i have a foreign key name `user_id`.

Here is how my `foadc_invoice` looks like:

[image]

Now in this as you can see i have `user_id` so in my `foadc_users` table i have fields structure like this:

[image]

Here in above table we have child - parent relationship between `id` and `under_id`.

Now i might have multiple children under children of a parent, this can a unlimited tree. **I want to calculate `total` month wise of the whole children tree of a specified parent.**

I am trying to do this in MySQL/Eloquent. But for this i am ok with raw query as well. I will convert to Eloquent.

**As per your suggestion here is the result:**
[image]

Comment: If height (max ) of tree is known  then is possible to get .... as there are no cte or like thing  in mysql ..

Comment: usually upto 6 level will be the max

Answer (score 1):

we do not have CTE in my sql so we have to use sub query.

if there are only two level  (ie ) 
 algo ...

step1   first  for each find its parent if there is no parent consider himself as it **parentID**.

repeat same step again and again (if max height is 4  then 4 time) .

step 2 now you will have child id and corresponding top level parent join this with  foadc_invoice and sum (ammount) and group by parentID.

sample for 2 level  for step 1

```
 SELECT   p.id as id ,  coalesce( c.id ,p.id )as under_id  FROM      foadc_users p  LEFT JOIN foadc_users c    ON  p.id =c.under_id
```

sample for 3 level  for step 1

```
  SELECT     p.id as id ,  coalesce( c.id ,p.id )as under_id   
      FROM 

             (SELECT   p.id as id , coalesce( c.id ,p.id )as under_id  FROM foadc_users p LEFT JOIN foadc_users c  ON  p.id =c.under_id) p
  LEFT JOIN foadc_users c
   ON  p.id =c.under_id
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. I am using this approch for the same 

`select  id,
        name,
        under_id 
from    (select * from foadc_users
         order by under_id, id) products_sorted,
        (select @pv := '1') initialisation
where   find_in_set(under_id, @pv) > 0
and     @pv := concat(@pv, ',', id)`.

Now i want to get data MONTHLY and join to foadc_invoice to get the total sum

Answer (score 0):

Try this

select fu.name, date_format('validafrom', '%M'), sum(amount) from  foadc_invoice fi left outer join foadc_users fu on fu.id=fi.user_id group by fu.name,date_format('validafrom', '%M')

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But the result looks like the attachment in last.

Comment: here instead of `validafrom ` i used `created_at` field as i have this field as well.

Comment: Can you also please suggest us how can we the the total of the children as well?

Comment: What column represents the childern in your table above? You can get the total row count by adding count(*) to select.